# Power law vs exponential law decay autocorrelation function. What is the difference

Tags: autocorrelation

Once I read that it is possible to speculate about decay type of the autocorrelation function (ACF). Unfortunately, I forgot the link and main idea. It sounds like if ACF decay is exponential, then my process has a short memory if power law than it has some long interactions.

**Could You help me to find some speculations about the shape of ACF?**

Comment: These uses of "short memory" and "long interactions" sound qualitative: would you be able to provide some quantitative descriptions or definitions of what you mean?

Comment: I could not provide the explanations of 'memory', moreover I am not sure it was about any memory. I just need to speculate what means, that time-series from group 1 have exponential, and time series from group 2 have power decay.